# Solr reload is not picking up the latest changes from Zookeeper

Tags: solr, reload, apache-zookeeper

Solr reload is not picking up the latest changes from Zookeeper.

**Configuration Details:**

- Solr: 6.0.0
- Zookeeper: 3.4.6
- OS: AWS Linux

We are facing an issue that when we RELOAD an existing collection in solr to pick up the latest configuration from zookeeper (which we upconfig in Zookeeper) the changes are not reflected on the collection. We verified the same using the solr admin ui. But the changes we made were available on zookeeper, we have verified the same by connecting to zookeeper using zkcli.sh script.

*Note: We are able to see the latest config picked correctly if we create a new collection based on the config we uploaded to zookeeper. Issue occurs only for the solr RELOAD call.*

Please help us narrow down the issue.

Comment: I have come accross this issue when reloading a configuration in 5.4.0, the only workaround i found was to recreate the core.

Comment: @KinSlayerUY - Are you meaning to create new collection every time to pick up the new conf?